# What programing language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

Someone know what kind of language used below:

```
String^ fileName = "C:\\Test1.txt";
array<Byte>^ Array = gcnew array<Byte>(512);
try
{
    FileStream^ fs = File::OpenRead(fileName);
    fs->Read(Array, 0, 512);fs->Close();
}
catch (...)
{ 
    MessageBox::Show("Disk error"); 
    Application::Exit();
}
```

and another example of that language:

```
int RotateLeft3 (int number)
{
    if ( ( number & 0x20000000 ) == 0x20000000 )
    {
        number <<= 3;number |= 1;
    }
    else
        number <<= 3;
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI), in other words the C++ variant that runs on top of the .Net CLR.

On no account should this be confused with native C++.

Answer (score 9):

Its C++ in .NET. You can tell by the use of ^ as pointer instead of *

Answer (score 3):

It looks like managed c++ from Microsoft.